# How would Blue/Yellow colored plants change during different weather seasons

Tags: planets, flora, sunlight, seasons, colors

My planet basically revolves around a blue star or a star that gives off more blue wavelengths, and the color of the plants are either blue or yellow or both because they are trying to absorb the most out of the blue wavelength. Now, how would the color change during the autumn months or winter months? (does winter change color of plants?)  Also is this color accurate for plants that on a planet would revolve around a blue star or a star that gives off more blue light?

Comment: Why is the planet named Greenia if the plants are blue and yellow? (The *chlor* in *chlorophyll* means green.)

Comment: i just though of name that sound nice there was no other reason is there a problem with that

Comment: There is a problem for any reader with a sufficiently large vocabulary. The name promises something and then the story does not deliver. Xanthea for yellow, Cyanea for blue.

Comment: and i didnt realzed it sounded like chlorophyll thats a coinceden i apoligze if i came off strong

Comment: earth is called earth after the ground but it also called the blue planet cuases of its oceancs see where im going not everything has to be literal or it does idk im new to worldbuilding jesus

Comment: also idk its a fictional world i can call it whaever i want

Comment: Photosynthetic pigments of plants don't absorb as much green (only 90%), so plants are green because they don't absorb green. A plant would lose pigments just like on Earth, so fall would likely look pretty normal. You might find this interesting https://www.quantamagazine.org/why-are-plants-green-to-reduce-the-noise-in-photosynthesis-20200730/

Comment: thank you someone finally awnserd insted of trash talking bout a name i thank you and hope you have a good day

Comment: so fall would just be in the oranges correct since the plants are yellow they would turn orange am i getting it right

Answer (score 2):

On our planet leaves get in different colors during fall: red, yellow, brown, some even remain green. It doesn't depend on the color of the star, but rather on the biological process behind the preparation for winter.

Basically what happens is that the plant, if dropping the leaves for the winter, decomposes the photosynthetic pigment and exposes the remaining pigments in the leave. Therefore in your case the leaves can be of any color you like, or better, if you figure out the biochemistry of the leaves you can get an idea of the possible colors.

Answer (score 1):

A plant that absorbed more blue light would be *orange*.  That is, the light that is reflected is the opposite of what's absorbed.  (Yes, terrestial plants are green when sunlight is rich in green light.  This is because they are not absorbing a wavelength that there is plenty of.  Botanists still ponder this.)

This fact gives you leeway in the color.  If they are blue, they are not absorbing blue light.  Perhaps this is to protect them from over-intense energy.  Perhaps they are black because they absorb all the light they can.  Whatever color you want, you can probably get.

Terrestrial deciduous plants have their leaves change color because the green-colored pigment vanishes as they die, leaving other, lesser important pigments to take their place.  Needle-bearing trees also lose the green when they shed, for the same reason.  You can do as you like, based on how the pigments in the leaves degrade, and in what order.